# PopUp from PORTRAIT TO LANDSPACE and vice versa, wrong dimensions

Tags: android, popup, orientation

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        int height = display.getHeight();
        final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(v,width-20,height-50,true);

}
```

When I run app in PORTRAIT and change orientation of the phone to LANDSPACE, the height of the popup is too hight, but when I run app in LANDSPACE and back to PORTRAIT I can see only a half of the popup (too wide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to write the same code in onconfigurationchanged() method. When u change the orientation activity will came into this method & not to onCreate() method. & check now it will give u current result.